# Data not displaying in the HTML file while using the api?

Tags: json, angular, api, shopping-cart, angular-ng-if

I am working on a shopping cart application. I'm facing issue while displaying the user selected products in the cart.component.html, as the data is not rendering. DOM is being created every time but the data is not displaying in the cart.component.html ? can anyone suggest how to solve this problem ?

cart.component.html

`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="products.length !=0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-table">
      <div class="cart-product">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Sr.No</th>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Product Image</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Total</th>
              <!-- <th>Action</th> -->
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
              <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
              <td>
                <img style="width: 120px" src="{{ item.image }}" alt="" />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 25%">{{ item.description }}</td>
              <th style="width: 12%">{{ item.price }}</th>
              <td style="width: 12%">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
              <td style="width: 12%">{{ item.total }}</td>
              <td>
                <!-- <button (click)="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button> -->
                <!-- </td> -->
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="4"></td>
              <!-- <td><button (click)="emptycart()" class="btn btn-danger">Empty Cart</button></td> -->
              <td>
                <button routerLink="/products" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Shop More
                </button>
              </td>
              <!-- <td><button class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button></td> -->
              <td>
                <strong>Grand Total : ${{ grandTotal }}</strong>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="products.length == 0">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-title">My Cart</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <img
        src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/www/800/800/promos/16/05/2019/d438a32e-765a-4d8b-b4a6-520b560971e8.png?q=90"
        alt=""
      />
      <h4>Your cart is empty!</h4>
      <h6>Add item to it now</h6>
      <button routerLink="/products" class="btn btn-primary">Shop Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

cart.component.ts

`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavbarserviceService } from 'src/app/navbarservice.service';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/service/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  public products : any = [];
  public grandTotal !: number;
  constructor(private cartService : CartService, public nav: NavbarserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nav.show();
    this.cartService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(res=>{
      
      this.products = res;
      this.grandTotal = this.cartService.getTotalPrice();
    });
  }
  // removeItem(item: any){
  //   this.cartService.removeCartItem(item);
  // }
  // emptycart(){
  //   this.cartService.removeAllCart();
  // }

}
```

cart.service.ts

`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from '../component/login/login.service';
import { UserCart } from './cart';
import { item } from './product';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  public cartItemList: any = []
  public productList = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  public search = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private login: LoginService) {
    console.log ("constrcutor called")
  }

  populateDataFromBackend() {
    console.log ("populateDataFromBackend called")
    var cartItemListLocal: any = []

    //return this.productList.asObservable();
    //Return data from backend
    var apiRequest: string = "http://localhost:3000/userCart?emailId=" + this.login.loggedInUserID;
    this.http.get<UserCart[]>(apiRequest)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        res.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element.emailId, element.productId);

          var getProductAPI: string = "http://localhost:3000/products?id=" + element.productId;
          this.http.get<item>(getProductAPI).subscribe(res => {
            //
            console.log(res);
            cartItemListLocal.push(res);

           // this.productList.next (res);
            // productListNew.next (cartItemListLocal);

          })

        });

      }

      )

    console.log("cartItemsLocal\n");

    console.log(cartItemListLocal);
    this.productList.next(cartItemListLocal);
  }

  getProducts() {
    this.populateDataFromBackend();
     
    return this.productList.asObservable();
  }

  setProduct(product: any) {
    this.cartItemList.push(...product);
    this.productList.next(product);
  }
  addtoCart(product: any) {

    var cartItem = new UserCart(this.login.loggedInUserID, product.id);

    console.log(cartItem, "cartItem");
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/userCart", cartItem).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log("Datasent to cart ", data);
      }
    )

    /*
    this.cartItemList.push(cartItem);

    
    
    this.productList.next(this.cartItemList);
    this.getTotalPrice();
    console.log(this.cartItemList,"this.cartItemlist")
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/userCart",this.cartItemList).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log("Datasent to cart ",data);
      }
    )
    */
  }
  getTotalPrice(): number {
    let grandTotal = 0;
    this.cartItemList.map((a: any) => {
      grandTotal += a.total;
    })
    return grandTotal;
  }
  // removeCartItem(product: any){
  //   this.cartItemList.map((a:any, index:any)=>{
  //     if(product.id=== a.id){
  //       this.cartItemList.splice(index,1);
  //     }
  //   })
  //   this.productList.next(this.cartItemList);
  // }
  // removeAllCart(){
  //   this.cartItemList = []
  //   this.productList.next(this.cartItemList);
  // }
}
```

product.ts

```
export class item {

id!: number;
title!: string;
price!: number;
description!: string;
category!: string;
image!: string;
/*
"rating": {
    "rate": 3.9,
    "count": 120
}*/
```

}

Comment: any error or something?

Comment: no errors, but data is not loading... into the html file.. only the dom is creating successfully.. i mean, in the html file, if there is 5 cart items to be displayed, then 5 rows are created.. like this dom is created every time, just data not loading...

Comment: Can I see the product class? And if you log the products you get how they looks like?

Comment: updated product.ts

Comment: Ok, looks good. I can't see any thing is wrong. Do you can create a Stackblitz example with your code?

Comment: sorry i dont know about it, is there any way i can provide you the additional details needed to you..

Comment: like db.json file, or cart.component.html file image. etc.. or any other file..

Comment: It's hard to say... if you have time stackblitz.com. You can create a simple angular project and share it here.

Comment: Can you add the following console.log and then tell us what it says?:


`this.cartService.getProducts().subscribe(res => console.log('Products:', res));`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling the http request in the constructor and doing the assignment there?

{{ item?.description }}

and others arrange table cells like this

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I would improve:

First, your interface (or model) product.ts is called item, but you are not using it anywhere. Try to do this:

```
export class Product {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  image: string;
}
```

Doing that, you can import it in your **component.ts** use it when you instantiate a product object, like this:

```
products : Product[] = [];
```

Try to do this every time it is possible since we are working with Angular (and TypeScript) and we must avoid using **any**.

As other people mentioned in the comments, the rest looks good, so try to do that and update the question.